# Using Apple Services in a sandboxed app

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, sandbox

My application is sandboxed. I added an item to the Services menu and when I try to select that menu item in another application, my application is not loaded and the service doesn't work.

The icon of my application appears in the Dock panel and disappears immediately. When I turn off sandboxing, everything is alright. I think I need to add some rows in `Entitlements.plist` but I don't know what.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What specific things is your app trying to do? We can't tell you what keys to use if we don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It sounds like your app is crashing when you run the service. When debugging sandbox issues, it is useful to pull up the Console app and look for any related messages, which should provide clues as to what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Add the key like this in your entitlement:

```
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
<array>
    <string>com.apple.itunes</string>
</array>
```

NOTE: This one means I want to send Apple events to iTunes, so you can get more information here: [App Sandbox Temporary Exception Entitlements](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html)